# Combining functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I'm working on a web application and I've found myself with about 1000 lines of code and noticed that a lot of my functions are exactly the same except for a few changes depending on context. For example the application I've built manages SharePoint so I'm either working with groups or I'm working with users. I'm trying to find the best way to reduce redundancy/duplication in my code.

This is what it looks like: [image]

Right now I have two functions, one which populates all my users and another with populates all my groups. I have other functions which are also very similar but have a few changes depending on what I'm working with.

JS:

```
  function populateGroups(){ 
    //Populate the group list  
    strHTMLSiteGroups = "";
    userAssigned.empty();
    userAvailable.empty();
    $("#my_SiteGroups option:gt(0)").remove();
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromSite",
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
          groupCollection = $(xData.responseXML);
          groupCollection.find("Group").each(function() {
          strHTMLSiteGroups += "<option value='" + $(this).attr("Name")+ "' data-groupid='" + $(this).attr("ID") + "'>" + $(this).attr("Name") + "</option>";
        });
          group.append(strHTMLSiteGroups);
          $('#groupOwner').append('<optgroup label="---Groups---"></optgroup>');
          $('#groupOwner').append(strHTMLSiteGroups);
        }
    });
  }
  function populateUsers() {
    //Populate the user list
    strHTMLSiteUsers = "";
    $("#my_SiteUsers option:gt(0)").remove(); //remove all except first
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetUserCollectionFromSite",
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
          userCollection = $(xData.responseXML);
          userCollection.find("User").each(function() {
            strHTMLSiteUsers += "<option value='" + $(this).attr("LoginName") + "' data-userid='"+ $(this).attr("ID")+ "'>" + $(this).attr("Name") + "</option>";
          });
          user.append(strHTMLSiteUsers);
          $('#groupOwner').append(strHTMLSiteUsers);
        }
    });
  }
```

I plan on using either Angular, Backbone or Knockoutjs with this application. I don't know them yet so it's something I'll have to learn. My goal however is to have one of these boxes, not two. From there have a controller (menu item) showing the user the option to work with users or groups. At that point have the view update to reflect items related to the context (user or group) and have one function to return either groups or users depending on which context I'm in.

Is there anyway to improve the functions I have below to do this or is having 2 functions for each context the way to go?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Is it best to have two functions even though they are very similar or should I combine them somehow.

Comment: It depends how different they are. If there is a chunk of code that is the same, you can take that out and make it a function that you call.

Answer (score 1):

This should combine the code of your 2 functions into 1:

```
function populateGroups() {
    populate('Groups', 'Name', group);
}

function populateUsers() {
    populate('Users', 'LoginName', user);
}

function populate(entity, nameKey, entityVar) {
    //Populate the list  
    strHTMLSite = "";
    if (entity == 'user') {
        userAssigned.empty();
        userAvailable.empty();
    }
    $("#my_Site" + entity + " option:gt(0)").remove();

    $("#my_SiteGroups option:gt(0)").remove();
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "Get" + entity + "GroupCollectionFromSite",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            collection = $(xData.responseXML);
            collection.find(entity).each(function () {
                strHTMLSite += "<option value='" + $(this).attr(nameKey) + "' data-" + entity.toLowerCase() + "id='" + $(this).attr("ID") + "'>" + $(this).attr("Name") + "</option>";
            });
            entityVar.append(strHTMLSiteGroups);
            if (entity == 'group') {
                $('#groupOwner').append('<optgroup label="---Groups---"></optgroup>');
            }
            $('#groupOwner').append(strHTMLSiteGroups);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, the difference between the two solutions is only 2 lines (35 vs 33). However, it is still a good idea to combine your code, as it will allow for fewer mistaked in the future. Updating code in one place, then forgetting to update it in a similar piece of code is one of the most common human mistakes in software development, and you can prevent is by not writing redundant code.

Comment: I like this solution. It's simple and doesn't require me to redo the same thing but using an IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two similar functions, you can reduce the number by adding a parameter. like this :

```
function populateThings(whatThings)
{
 //Populate the list
    strHTMLSiteUsers = "";
    $("#my_Site" + whatThings + "s option:gt(0)").remove(); //remove all except first
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetUserCollectionFromSite",
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
          userCollection = $(xData.responseXML);
          userCollection.find(whatThings).each(function() { 
            strHTMLSiteUsers += "<option value='" + $(this).attr("LoginName") + "' data-userid='"+ $(this).attr("ID")+ "'>" + $(this).attr("Name") + "</option>";
          });
          user.append(strHTMLSiteUsers);
          $('#groupOwner').append(strHTMLSiteUsers);
        }
    });
}
```

etc..

Comment: So if I had a menu to my application with User and Group, i guess I could create an event that would set the var whatThings to wither user or group based on which menu item was clicked, and from there pass that variable into the populate function?

Answer (score 0):

DRY principle is definitely what you need. I would recommend to have one function but add some parameters, like:

```
function populate(entity)
{
  // common code
  if (entity === "User") {
    // put specific code for User here..
  }
  if (entity === "Group") {
    // put specific code for Group here..
  }
}
```